# Daisy Chain Methods in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm new to .NET and C#, coming from a background in Ruby. While I've successfully developed a couple of small applications in C#, I still have a lot to learn. One thing that is puzzling me though, is finding an efficient way to call multiple methods on an object. I'll give an example using strings.

I'm used to being able to do something like this in Ruby:

```
my_string = "The quick brown fox\tjumped over the lazy dog\t\n"
puts my_string.strip.split("\t")
```

However, to accomplish the same thing in C#, this Is all I know to do right now:

```
var myString = "The quick brown fox\tjumped over the lazy dog\t\n";
var myStringTrim = myString.Trim();
var myStringSplit = myStringTrim.Split('\t');
foreach (var s in myStringSplit)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

So, is there a more efficient way to accomplish this in C#?

This particular example makes me wonder what would happen to performance if I were to use this method to read, parse, and process a large text file or something like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do `myString.Trim().Split('\t');` in C#

You can do that, because `Trim()` returns a `string` object, which you can then call `Split()` on, which returns an array.

But it's not necessarily more 'efficient'. Interim objects are being created, even if you aren't storing them in variables.

Comment: ok...I've got a lot to learn. Thanks, to everyone, for such a quick response.

Comment: This is known as [Fluent Interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Answer (score 4):

this works just fine...

```
var myString = "The quick brown fox\tjumped over the lazy dog\t\n".Trim().Split('\t');
```

these methods are instance methods of the string object, and will work just as you expect them  to do in Ruby.

the one thing to keep in mind is that string is immutable. that is, these methods do not change the original value of the string variable, but return a modified copy of the original.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain these commands together like this:

```
myString.Trim().Split('\t').ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

Comment: .ForEach can't guarantee speed. In fact it might be the opposite

Comment: @Hao why would you think it might be the opposite?